# COMO REALIZAR UNA CONSULTA QUE DEVUELVA LA CANTIDAD DE REGISTROS EN UNA TABLA

Tags: mysql, sql

- Buenos dias, disculpen quisiera saber como se pudiera modificar esta consulta para que me devuelva el total de registros, la siguiente consulta me devuelve todos los productos que estan incluidos en una venta, entre ellos cada producto tiene su fabricante y su direccion, pero resulta que cada producto puede tener fabricantes y direcciones diferentes o iguales es decir pueden haber datos repetidos, entonces lo que hice fue utilizar un distint y un group by para que me trajera solo una vez las direcciones y fabricantes que se repiten por decir, tengo 19 productos con sus direcciones y fabricantes con los cuales pueden existir: SALVADOR -> 7 veces, Guatemala -> 7 veces HONDURAS -> 5 veces entonces la consulta solo devuelve: SALVADOR, GUATEMALA, HONDURAS.
- Lo que quiero saber es como modificar para que la consulta me diga CONTEO -> 3 que es el total de direcciones que existen.
- CONSULTA ORIGINAL

  ```
  SELECT (DISTINCT h.art_adress) as direccion
  FROM 
  vnt_cotizacion a,
  vnt_detalle_cotizacion b,
  sis_cliente c,
  inv_articulo d,
  inv_categoria e,
  inv_marca f ,
  inv_articulo_cumplimiento g,
  inv_articulo_exportacion h,
  inv_categoria_export i 
  WHERE b.dven_cotizacion = a.ven_codigo 
  AND b.dven_articulo = d.art_codigo
  AND a.ven_cliente = c.cli_codigo 
  AND d.art_categoria = e.cat_codigo 
  AND d.art_marca = f.mar_codigo 
  AND g.articuloId = b.dven_articulo
  AND h.art_codigo_interno = b.dven_articulo
  AND i.id_categoria_export = d.art_categoria_export
  AND a.ven_codigo IN(686) 
  GROUP BY h.art_adress
  ORDER BY h.art_adress
  ```
- [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
- CONSULTA COUNT (la que quiero corregir)

  ```
  SELECT DISTINCT h.art_adress, COUNT(*)
  FROM 
  vnt_cotizacion a,
  vnt_detalle_cotizacion b,
  sis_cliente c,
  inv_articulo d,
  inv_categoria e,
  inv_marca f ,
  inv_articulo_cumplimiento g,
  inv_articulo_exportacion h,
  inv_categoria_export i
  WHERE b.dven_cotizacion = a.ven_codigo 
  AND b.dven_articulo = d.art_codigo
  AND a.ven_cliente = c.cli_codigo 
  AND d.art_categoria = e.cat_codigo 
  AND d.art_marca = f.mar_codigo 
  AND g.articuloId = b.dven_articulo
  AND h.art_codigo_interno = b.dven_articulo
  AND i.id_categoria_export = d.art_categoria_export
  AND a.ven_codigo IN(686) 
  GROUP BY h.art_adress
  ORDER BY h.art_adress
  ```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- La consulta me devuelve que hay una direccion que se repite 2 veces, null se repite 9 veces, una direccion se repite solo 1 vez y hay 7 espacios en blanco, entonces ese conteo no me sirve, lo que necesito que me diga: direccion -> 4

Comment: ¿Has probado con `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ...`?

Comment: Si lo estas agrupando por art_adress no puede haber dos adress repetidas estas haciendo un group by fijo que alguna de ellas dos es diferente o tiene un espacio de mas que no estas viendo o algo similar.

Comment: select count (distinct art_adress)??? igual todos esos joins no tienen mucho sentido.. o no parecerian tenerlo...

Comment: bien los joins son necesarios, porque esos hacen la funcion de traerme los productos que tiene cada venta, probe select count(distinct art_adress) y no me funciono